# How to extract the values from the response body in postman and store as variable

Tags: postman

I am trying to extract the sys_id value and store it as a variable within postman. Currently I am not getting any errors using the following

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set('sys_id', pm.response.json().sys_id);
```

It is saving the variable, but showing null within the value
[image]
**Response Body**

```
{
"result": {
    "sys_id": "5ae690c11ba421d46557a9b7bd4bcbbf",
}}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please use `pm.response.json()` and not `JSON.parse(responseBody)` - It does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the whole value of the response body - and based on [this link](https://community.postman.com/t/extract-value-from-a-json-response-body-via-the-test-scripts/11835/2), you can try this code - which I tested with another JSON data payload:

Code:

```js
let data = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('sys_id', data.result.sys_id);
console.log(pm.variables.get("sys_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it with the following code:

```
var responseData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("sys_id", responseData.result.sys_id);
```

Comment: You should accept the other answer, as the solution and give Marco the credit.